How do I draw a line between two coordinates in the TWebLeafletMaps component?
In this blog post, they clearly show how to draw a line between coordinates:
procedure TForm2.WebFileUpload1GetFileAsText(Sender: TObject; AFileIndex: Integer; AText: string);  
var  
  ja: TJSArray;  
begin  
  ja := GPXToCoordinates(AText);  
  WebLeafletMaps1.AddPolyLine(ja, clBlue, 3);
end;

So you can draw lines using the AddPolyLine function, but I'm having some trouble with what to pass to the AddPolyLine function. They're using the GPXToCoordinates function to convert a GPX file to a TJSArray, but how should this array look?
How can I use my own custom coordinates for the AddPolyLine function? I don't want to use a GPX file.

This is how you can draw a line between two points on the map without needing to use a GPX file:
procedure TForm1.WebFormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyCoordinates: TJSArray;
begin
  MyCoordinates := TJSArray.New;
  asm
    MyCoordinates = [
      [-27.1251322, 23.1663553],
      [-28.1244564, 26.1643535]
    ];
  end;


  WebLeafletMaps1.AddPolyLine(MyCoordinates, clBlue, 3);
end;


But you left out the most important information. You did not clarify what those numbers mean. Are they pixels or geographic coordinates and if so, then according to what definition?

@TomBrunberg They are geographic coordinates (latitude and longitude)

So, according to what is said here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system ?

@TomBrunberg Seems like it. I found this: "The Leaflet package expects all point, line, and shape data to be specified in latitude and longitude using WGS 84 (a.k.a. EPSG:4326)". It's basically the same coordinate system that Google Maps uses. You can get coordinates of locations straight from Google Maps and use it in Leaflet with OpenStreetMap and it works with the correct location.
